# How can I make the transition from blue to purple (I do not want the white part) more smooth?

Tags: node-editor

When using a gradient node and a color ramp, Even though a gradient should be smooth, I get sharp edges separating the colors in the color ramp. Also, there is this white part that comes out of nowhere. Help! I use blender 2.82 and windows.

[image: Node Setup]

[image: Result]

Comment: Hello :). This happens because Emission strength is more than 1. Increasing emission gradually turns all colors into white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your setup, the emission shader is causing that white strip.  In the pic below, I set it up exactly as you did, but I bypassed the emission shader.

[image]

Comment: You forgot to say you set the interpolation to "Cardinal" instead of "Linear"

Comment: Hey :). *Viewer node* is actually just *Emission node* only with Strength = 1. That's why the colors stay accurate.